# Rcurl : Calling to API

Tags: r, curl

After lurking still unable to find a good answer to this...

I am trying to pull data from this API here:

http://code.flashtalking.net/

The setup from what I understand is :

```
URL : https://request.flashtalking.net/authenticate/mytoken
Authorization : Username Password
GET
```

In Rcurl I have :

```
getURL(https://request.flashtalking.net/authenticate/mytoken ,
userpwd = "blah@email.com:Password" 
, .opts = list(ssl.verifypeer = FALSE) ,  verbose = TRUE )
```

I getting 403 Error of being Forbidden.

Is my syntax here correct or should I be calling this differently?

Comment: What type of error are you getting? 404 is not found, 403 is forbidden and 401 is not authorized. Those are different. Also, try adding in `httpauth = 1L` after the `userpwd=` parameter if it doesn't seem to be authenticating.

Comment: Sorry, it is 403 Forbidden.  I will try with the httpauth .

Comment: Did it make any difference? From what i can tell it appears to be the correct format. If it still doesn't work, i'd contact those at http://code.flashtalking.net/ to see if they can provide a more details description and perhaps a sample of an appropriate "authenticate" request.

Comment: Got rid of the error but now my Get returns nothing and closes out. I am going to contact them out the issue.

Comment: You really get nothing? Just a blank response? How are you inspecting the return value? you should be getting XML according to the docs.

Comment: @cutty14 did you ever figure this out?